# Android:Cannot set current date each time to date picker

Tags: android, date, datepicker, android-simon-datepicker

I am using `DatePicker` to show the date to the user in my application.
    However, I am using **onCreateDialog** method to show the date picker to the user, setting the integer variable as follows:
    **static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;**
    Then I am calling below method
    **showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);**

First time the date picker initialized with current date. Everything is fine till now.

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("Executed", "hihihihihihihi");
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // set date picker as current date
                DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, datePickerListener, myear, mmonth,
                        mday) {



                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        if (year < myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    }

                };
                return _date;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

But the problem is when i selects date other than current date it works.but when i again tries to select date the date picker by default shows me last selected date.I am unable to set current date each time when  date picker opens so how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use date picker from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

Add the below method and class in your activity:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: but it is in my Activity

Comment: Chintan soni giving error to line newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); that can not resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: @Dhiraj Make sure you are writing the code in activity and not in fragment.

Comment: trying your solution will let you know about my progress attempting to put your solution in my main app

Comment: ohh sry due to weekend i could not tell you the status it's working bro...!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private Calendar c; 

@Override
onCreate(){

c = Calendar.getInstance();

}



@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        final int myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("Executed", "hihihihihihihi");
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // set date picker as current date
                DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, datePickerListener, myear, mmonth,
                        mday) {




                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                         /// Here you can set your updated date to calendar instance. So whenever you open it again, it will display last updated date
                         c.set(year, (monthOfYear- 1), dayOfMonth);

                        if (year < myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    }

                };
                return _date;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Have you checked updated answer ? I updated my answer few minutes ago. Please go through  that and let me know, its working or not !

Comment: when i am selecting date it is asigned to button as text immeadiately when i tries to change date it not shows me current date it shows me previously selected date

Answer (score 0):

(English is not my first language, please correct if necessary)

I think your condition checking is wrong,

```
if (year < myear)
   view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
    view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
    view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);
```

For example: By default you are setting current date to today(13/2/2016).

**Step 1:**

In datePicker by default date is 13/2/2016. Now you selecting previous day (12/2/2016)

Now datepicker value become 12/2/2016.

In this case,

if(year < myear) = false

if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear) = false

if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth) = true

**Step 2**

Now again you are changing the datepicker date to today's date (13/2/2016)

In this case:

if(year < myear) = false

if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear) = false

**if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth) = false** - this case become false, because dayOfMonth and mday are the same. but you are checking for earlier dates.